# Portainer registry authentication

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have setup portainer and registry to run in containers on the same host, but i cant create containers from Portainer.

I have added host as local endpoint and the registry to portainer with username and password.

When i try to create a container i get "Failure invalid reference format", nothing shows in portainer logs but in registry logs i get:

```
"error authorizing context: authorization token required"
```

I can log into the registry with docker login from the host, i also have Portus running in container on same host which successfully accesses the registry.

I have also tried using the --ssl --sslcert and --sslkey flags with generated certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you created the registry in the Portainer settings > Registries section right? This is probably a format error in the Registry URL field, you need to specify the URL to your registry without specifying the protocol (e.g. 10.10.10.10:5000 and not http://10.10.10.10.5000 for example).

If you need support, you can join us on Slack at https://portainer.io/slack/

Comment: Yes i added through portainer settings > registries without the protocol.

Comment: Usually on portainer slack channel newbies are just ignored.